# Django scheduling a script using Schedule

Tags: python, django

Im trying to schedule a script that i have made to scrape data from a website. The function im trying to schedule is ment to add the data to the database and also check if it exits. This is the function and how i implemendet schedule.

```
def scrapedata():

    car_data = carscraper()

    for i in car_data:
        car = CarModel.objects.create(
            title = i[0],
            img_url = i[1],
            link = i[2],
            model_year = i[3],
            mileage = i[4],
            price = i[5],
        )
        if CarModel.objects.filter(title=i[0]).exists() == False:
            car.save()

schedule.every(20).seconds.do(scrapedata)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is that the sever never runs when i have this script. Ive placed the code i my views.py. so this code that i pasted is my views.py for my application. The error i get when trying doing this is:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

Im powershell. Ive just learned to use the schedule libarary so i must be doing somthing wrong. Any ideas? And if you know any better ways to do this feel free to comment, open for any sulutions.